# Analytics and legality issues

Tags: ios, analytics, flurry

If you ever used Analytics in your apps, have you included information disclosing that you're collecting Information from them? Or do you omit this? It will be my first time using Analytics and I just wanted to hear your opinions on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes! In certain countries you have to add information that you are collecting information (even if that happens anonymously)! For example here in Germany we have really strict privacy rules: You have to exactly specify what you are logging (if you can't/don't you could get into trouble when selling your app here). My 2 cents: Decide whether you actually _need_ analytics. Do you _really_ need to know how long/where your app is opened? Or will you _actively_ adapt your app by the collected data? Don't steal your customers' privacy if they have no benefit at all.

Comment: Paul, you've brought up another good point. I haven't though about the requirements for all the countries that my app could potentially be used/downloaded. My main reason for using Analytics initially was to track where users spend most of their time rather than their own personal information. Im more interested in learning which areas I should make future enhancements.

Comment: Remember: If you collect this through the well-known analytics services like Flurry or GA you're tracking way more. If you are able to afford a (small) server you could do the following: Write an own analytics server and the client API yourself. With this construct you can analyze things **the way you need them**. Rather than using site views/events in Flurry/GA you can track the _actual_ events more accurate/more deeply. You also don't have to struggle with the companies behind those services. However you'll be responsible for all tracking then which might be even more ... critical.

Answer (score 1):

Be transparent about it. Tell the user `that` you are collecting data, explain `what` you are collecting and give them the possibility to opt-out.

Currently there is a lot of talk about address books and photos being uploaded without user consent. You want to ensure that your users understand what you are collecting and that you respect them and their personal data.

You might want to look at Localytics. Their library is open source therefore you can see what data collected and you can enable logging to see what would be uploaded. Using their services would save you from setting up your own server.

The `tagEvent:` would be useful to gather where the users spend their time, there is probably no need to go for a paid plan.

Comment: Good idea, Olaf.  After hearing from the responses so far, I think I'm going to hold off on using analytics in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always safe (legally) to use anonymous information.  If you are collecting information and linking it to an email or an account, then you really should tell the people what you are doing.

No matter what, it would be best/required in some places to have a notice somewhere in the app that you are collecting data.

Comment: Thanks for your input! What if you don't collect any personal information but the time the users spend on a screen or which screens theyve used. Will one still need to disclose they're collecting that info?

Comment: here is a pretty good presentation about it, its a little dated, but shows a lot of the case law.  Basicly, if your not going to use the data for anything but your own purposes, then it is probably ok not to tell them, however, since your not giving them any way to opt out, you could get people upset.  http://goo.gl/770FH

Comment: Thanks for the link! =) It's has very useful info.